# Microsoft Reporting Service Textbox Alignment in Expression.

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I'm trying to set the textbox alignment depending on its content.

I have

```
= Replace(Fields!1_Text.Value, " " , chr(13) & CHR(10))
```

in value expression. 
Where should I put

```
  iif(fields!Allignment.Value = "C", "Center", "Right")
```

to align as coded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an aggregate function, such as first(), around your fields:

```
Iif(First(Fields!Allignment.Value,"DataSet1") = "C","Center","Right")
```

(alignment is misspelled...)

Comment: Where does "= Replace(Fields!1_Text.Value, " " , chr(13) & CHR(10))" go? I mean the Textbox should display the "1_Text.Value" and aligned by "Alignment.Value". Can you show an example?

Comment: Glad you figured it out - I didn't realize you didn't know about the expression button - glad you found it!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
Well, I didn't know that I could add an expression for the text alignment property. 
Steps are:

Textbox - go to Properties - "TextAlign" property - Expression

I could add an expression for "TextAlign" property like:

```
Iif(First(Fields!Allignment.Value,"DataSet1") = "C","Center","Right")
```

Cheers,